# jQuery - deferred and promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm a bit new to deferred and promises and I got code as follows:

```
  function validateAndSave(){
     var def = $.Deferred();
     validateAPIcall.done(function (errorCount) {
          if(errorCount > 0)
             def.reject(errorCount);
          else {
             //do something
             def.resolve();
          }
     });
    return def.promise();
  }


  function sth(){
     validateAndSave().done(function () {
         loadUI(0);
     }).fail(function (errorCount){
         loadUI(errorCount);
     });
  }
```

trying to understand if we can combine validateAndSave().done() and validateAndSave().fail() parts into one or is there any function that can handle/execute both def.reject and def.resolve?

Comment: Do not use `done` and `fail`, but proper promise methods like `catch` which allow chaining. And don't use deferreds/promises at all here, if you are not doing anything asynchronous!

Comment: validateAPIcall is asynchronous, it makes call to sql SP and get errors

Comment: [deferred.then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) can accept two functions, one for success and one for fail. Or it also seems like you could call `loadUI` directly in the `validateAPIcall.done`...

Comment: Thanks @David784, this is what I was looking for